# Finding $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+2}\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like some help in calculating the following double sum, which appears as an intermediary on one number-theoretic problem I was trying to advance. Below you can also see what I have tried, but because of that $(-1)^n$ it cannot be telescoped; at least not like that... So, here we are: (interchanging the order of summation is allowed because absolute convergence is easy by telescoping and using some strict inequalities)

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+2}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{k(2n+1)(n+1)}=\\=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor}^\infty (-1)^n\left( \frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2} \right)$$

Note: Wolfram hints that it is close to 1.25721...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n H_{2n+2}}{(n+1)(2n+1)}=2\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n H_{2n+2}\left(x^{2n}-x^{2n+1}\right)\,dx \tag{1}$$
provides a solid starting point. We may notice that
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}H_{n+1} x^{n} = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{x(1-x)}\tag{2}$$
for any $x\in(-1,1)$, hence the RHS of $(1)$ equals
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{x^2+x^4}\left(2x\arctan(x)+\log(1+x^2)\right)\,dx \tag{3}$$
that is a manageable integral through the [dilogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) machinery.
With the help of Mathematica I got:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n H_{2n+2}}{(n+1)(2n+1)}=\color{blue}{2 G+\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{5 \pi^2}{48}-\log(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)+\frac{\log^2(2)}{4}}\tag{4}$$
with $G$ being Catalan's constant. Numerically, the RHS of $(4)$ is $\approx 1.25721327371289764$.

Comment: Anyway, I still do not know if the most common notation for Catalan's constant is $G$ or $K$, I keep switching between such two. Any pointers are appreciated :)

Comment: Great, I was expecting Catalan's constant to appear somewhere in it...